# Laravel 5 - Inline CSS in email

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, html-email, laravel-blade

I am working on my first Laravel 5 project and desperately need a way to inline CSS from my email views. I am using Mailgun because of delivery issues with Mandrill (unfortunately, Mandrill has CSS inline capability baked in but Mailgun does not).

It appears that most packages out there for inlining CSS on emails for Laravel are out of date, most stopped working correctly on version 4.2. I have tried:

[Inlining CSS when sending an email with Mailgun in Laravel - Antoine Augusti](http://blog.antoine-augusti.fr/2014/06/inlining-css-when-sending-an-email-with-mailgun-in-laravel/) - does not seem to do anything, emails are not inlined. It appears that there are several fundamental differences in L5 that break this approach

[fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner](https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner) - Does not work. Someone posted some code at the end of this [Issue](https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner/issues/7) but I cannot figure out how to implement it (also do not know if it was intended for Laravel 5).

[bweston92/laravel-inline-css-mailer](https://github.com/bweston92/laravel-inline-css-mailer) - Looks promising but does not seem to do anything, CSS is not being inlined.

Does anyone have any recommendations? I would really like to be able to inline CSS for email, especially when I'm injecting HTML prior to sending (from WYSIWYG editor).

Comment: Just an advise, post your new class as answer to your question instead of embedding it on your question ;)

Comment: I'm hoping there are better suggestions..

Comment: I understand, but you can post it as answer and don't accept it, expecting that someone gives you a better answer

Comment: True, true. Will post in a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inspired by [bweston92/laravel-inline-css-mailer](https://packagist.org/packages/bweston92/laravel-inline-css-mailer), which I could not get to work, I came up with this little class using the [TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles) package. Please feel free to offer suggestions or point me in a better direction, just needed something quickly.

```
    <?php namespace App\Library;

    use TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles;

    /**

 * Class inlineEmail
 * 
 * Returns rendered Email view with inlined CSS
 * @package App\Library
 */
class inlineEmail {
    /**
     * Filename of the view to render
     * @var string
     */
    private $view;
    /**
     * Data - passed to view
     * @var array
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @param string $view Filename/path of view to render
     * @param array $data Data of email
     */
    public function __construct($view, array $data)
    {
        // Render the email view
        $emailView = view($view, $data)->render();
        $this->view = $emailView;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Convert to inlined CSS
     * 
     * @return string
     * @throws \TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\Exception
     */
    public function convert()
    {
        $converter = new CssToInlineStyles();
        $converter->setUseInlineStylesBlock();
        $converter->setCleanup();
        $converter->setStripOriginalStyleTags();
        $converter->setHTML($this->view);
        $content =  $converter->convert();

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$data = ['someVar' => 'someValue'];
        $inlineEmail = new inlineEmail('emails.group-email', $data);
        $content  = $inlineEmail->convert();
        Mail::queue('emails.raw', ['content' => $content], function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->subject('Hello World')
                ->to('support@somewhere.org')
                ->bcc($data['recipients']);
        });
```

The converted, inlined HTML/CSS is then passed to `emails.raw`, which contains only `{!! $content !!}`.

Here is the template I use for the majority of my emails - it is essentially a minimal version of Bootstrap for email. I'd give credit to its author but having trouble tracking down exactly where I found it, if someone knows please leave a comment. There are many other templates out there, just search for Bootstrap Email Template or HTML Email Boilerplate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Email Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            width: 100%!important;
            height: 100%;
        }
        a {
            color: #348eda;
        }
        .btn-primary {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #348eda;
            border: solid #348eda;
            border-width: 10px 20px;
            line-height: 2;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .btn-secondary {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #aaa;
            border: solid #aaa;
            border-width: 10px 20px;
            line-height: 2;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .last {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .first {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        .padding {
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        table.body-wrap {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        table.body-wrap .container {
            border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
        }
        table.footer-wrap {
            width: 100%;
            clear: both!important;
        }
        .footer-wrap .container p {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #666;

        }
        table.footer-wrap a {
            color: #999;
        }
        h1, h2, h3 {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.1;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            color: #000;
            margin: 40px 0 10px;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-weight: 200;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 36px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 28px;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 22px;
        }
        p, ul, ol {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        ul li, ol li {
            margin-left: 5px;
            list-style-position: inside;
        }
        .container {
            display: block!important;
            max-width: 600px!important;
            margin: 0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
            clear: both!important;
        }
        .body-wrap .container {
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .content {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
        }
        .content table {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
<!-- Main Body -->
<table class="body-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <img src="https://example.com/images/logo.png" alt="Company Logo"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Email content goes here .. -->
                    @yield('content')
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /Main Body -->
<!-- Footer -->
<table class="footer-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <p>Footer goes here</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /Footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

A typical email that extends this view would look something like this:

```
@extends('emails.template')
@section('content')
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>Example Email</h1>
            <p>This is an example email. There are many like it but this one is mine.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <p>
                <a href="http://example.com" class="btn-primary">This is a Button</a>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endsection
```

Comment: I tried your class as well, but I don't see where do you convert your css ?? I added this line in the convert function :      $css       = file_get_contents(public_path(). '/css/main.css');       to convert css as well, but the layout is not 100% how I expected to be !

Comment: Are you using Laravel and have you installed CssToInlineStyles via Composer?

Comment: In the class I convert the CSS in the convert() method. In use, you call this method on the instance - $content = $inlineEmail->convert(). You pass in your regular email view when creating an instance of this class, inline it, and then echo the resulting inlined view to emails.raw, containing simply {!! $content !!}}. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: me too, I added the lines to convert and set inline css in convert function, some styles are applied like fonts ,,, but others don't

Comment: Hmmm. I'll update my answer with the email template I use in a little while. Sounds like a CSS or inliner issue.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to your issue but make sure that you're using `{!! $content !!}` and not `{{ $content }}` in `emails.raw`

Comment: Not really ... I somehow gave up looking for an answer cuz I have a lot of other stuff to deploy ;)